# Dual boot mac with ubuntu boots from refind into grub instead of ubuntu

Tags: macos, unix, big-sur, dual-boot, grub

Here is what I have done so far:
I wanted to dual-boot my mac with ubuntu. I did this following the classic guides, except instead of clicking on the installer I opened it with the command "ubiquity -b" in the terminal (since I was getting a grub error).
The download worked this way and I also successfully installed rEFInd.

Here is my problem (see pictures below):
When I start my mac the refind screen pops up with my ubuntu and mac OS. Yet when I choose Ubuntu I get to a grub screen.

How to I get to the normal Ubuntu screen? I ran some ls commands so you can see what I am working with (feel free to ask for more pictures with other commands).
Also: is the error I get im picture 2 a sign of a problem?

[image: refind screen]

[image: grub screen with example commands]

[image: edit]

Comment: What does `ls (hd0,1)/efi/refind/drivers_x64/` show? In other words, is the driver installed that allows rEFInd to read Linux volumes?

Comment: @DavidAnderson It gives an error since that is not in refind - I added a picture of everything in refind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a grubless Ubuntu is installed, the rEFInd boot manager can be used to instruct the firmware to boot Ubuntu. However for this to happen, a Linux filesystem driver has to loaded first. In your case, the rEFInd boot manager will load the driver, if the `ext4_x64.efi` file exists in the `efi/refind/drivers_x64` folder on the same volume rEFInd is installed. You should be able to find the `ext4_x64.efi` file on the same media as downloaded with rEFInd.

From macOS , you should be able to mount the EFI volume where rEFInd is installed by using the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil mount disk0s1
```

You can unmount by using the command given below.

```
diskutil unmount disk0s1
```

You may also have other reasons for your problems. This answer just identifies one problem determined from the information you posted.

Comment: For everyone trying this, here is what I ended up doing: The the refind file I downloaded from the internet inside the refind folder I copied the whole 'drivers_x64' file and pasted it into the refind file on EFI (mounted with the command above).